# System.Web.HttpException: The SaveAs method is configured to require a rooted path, and the path is not rooted

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

The error that I'm facing is :

```
System.Web.HttpException: The SaveAs method is configured to require a rooted path, and the path '~\FileUpload\2019\HS-123.png' is not rooted.
```

which I find is a bit weird since my code here:

```
   Dim folderPath1 As String = ("~\FileUpload\" & Today.Year.ToString & "\")
   If fileuploadSituation.HasFile Then
                    Dim extension As String = (Path.GetExtension(fileuploadSituation.FileName))

                    fileuploadSituation.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(folderPath1) & ID + extension)

   End If
```

this code here work fine. But not this code:

```
 If fileuploadSuggest.HasFile Then

                    Dim extension1 As String = (Path.GetExtension(fileuploadSuggest.FileName))


                    fileuploadSuggest.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(folderPath1) & ID + extension1)

 End If
```

It work for the fileuploadSituation but not fileUploadSuggest even though they use the same path. Is there anything suggestion that I could use to apply?

Comment: `FileUpload` folder, where does it actually exist?

Comment: The error message is telling you that there is an issue with the value you're passing to `SaveAs`.  That value is the result of `Server.MapPath(folderPath1) & ID + extension`.  You haven't bothered to let us know what that value is.  Have you even looked to see for yourself?  If you're told something is wrong, look at that something to see what it is and, if you want others to help you, show them what it is too.

Comment: The FileUpload folder exist for sure and it resides in the project folder ,and the fileuploadSituation can upload just fine but not fileuploadSuggest which is the problem. the value of ( Server.MapPath(folderPath1) & ID + extension) is already stated above with the error statement which is '~\FileUpload\2019\HS-123.png'

Comment: @jmcilhinney `~\FileUpload\2019\HS-123.png`

Comment: If i were you i would save to "HS-123.png" only and see if it saves, then i would try to save it elsewhere

Comment: what happens if you save to `FileUpload\2019\HS-123.png`?

Comment: saving it at 'FileUpload\2019\HS-123.png' will go the 'C:\' directory instead under the project folder.

Comment: how about using `Application.StartupPath()`?

Comment: haven't tried application.StartupPath() yet. will let you updated once I tried it.

Comment: so I've tried Application.StartupPath() . the method does not work .

Comment: @Devcon, `Application.StartupPath` is specific to Windows Forms.

Comment: @NiceGuy, sorry, should have scrolled to see entire error message.

Comment: Obviously `Server.MapPath` is not doing what's expected.  Could it be because you have your slashes the wrong way?  `MapPath` is supposed to convert a URL to a file system path, so the source should use "/" as delimiters and the result will use "\".

Comment: I've already tried use '/' instead of '\' yet the result still maintain the same. If the server.MapPath does not work then FileUploadSituation shouldn't be able to work. in this case only the fileuploadsuggest the one did not work.

Comment: This is asp? When i see vb.net tag i assume it's windows forms or console app :)